# Ruby behaves differently in windows task scheduler

Tags: ruby, windows, scheduled-tasks

Ruby won't recognize directories when run from the task scheduler. I've had similar issues with ruby when running from the windows task scheduler.

Can anyone explain why ruby behaves this way when run from the Windows Task Scheduler?

Consider the following directory on my desktop

> (d)test
>   ----(d)One
>   ----(d)Two
>   ----(d)Three
>   ----(f)dirs.rb
>   ----(f)log.log

(d) = Directory
(f) = file

Consider the following Ruby script.

```
require 'logger'

log = Logger.new("C:/Users/crosson.Z7NETWORKS/Desktop/test/log.log", 'daily')
log.level = Logger::INFO

Dir.new("C:/Users/crosson.Z7NETWORKS/Desktop/test").each do |file|
log.info "%7s a dir? %s" % [file, File.directory?(file)]
end
```

Below is a result of the log when run from the command line.

```
I, [2011-08-30T12:50:47.700617 #5356]  INFO -- :       . a dir? true
I, [2011-08-30T12:50:47.700617 #5356]  INFO -- :      .. a dir? true
I, [2011-08-30T12:50:47.700617 #5356]  INFO -- : dirs.rb a dir? false
I, [2011-08-30T12:50:47.700617 #5356]  INFO -- : log.log a dir? false
I, [2011-08-30T12:50:47.700617 #5356]  INFO -- :     One a dir? true
I, [2011-08-30T12:50:47.700617 #5356]  INFO -- :   Three a dir? true
I, [2011-08-30T12:50:47.701617 #5356]  INFO -- :     Two a dir? true
```

Below is a result of the log when run from the task scheduler

```
I, [2011-08-30T13:03:07.187316 #5972]  INFO -- :       . a dir? true
I, [2011-08-30T13:03:07.188316 #5972]  INFO -- :      .. a dir? true
I, [2011-08-30T13:03:07.188316 #5972]  INFO -- : dirs.rb a dir? false
I, [2011-08-30T13:03:07.188316 #5972]  INFO -- : log.log a dir? false
I, [2011-08-30T13:03:07.188316 #5972]  INFO -- :     One a dir? false
I, [2011-08-30T13:03:07.188316 #5972]  INFO -- :   Three a dir? false
I, [2011-08-30T13:03:07.188316 #5972]  INFO -- :     Two a dir? false
```

Notice that my directories, One, Two and Three are no longer considered directories. What gives?

Comment: I did that earlier. When I try and grab the File.stat logger just doesn't log anything. Its like the File.stat method is prevented from running on anything other than "." and "..". I tried to add `File.stat(file).mtime`. It basically just skipped processing everything except the current dir "." and the above dir "..".

Comment: I also just tried changing permissions of my user account to Log on as a batch. Still the problem persists. [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755659(WS.10).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete guess, but what user is the Windows Task Scheduler using to run the script? I dimly remember issues with the task scheduler due to that process not having the same constellation of rights as me.

Comment: I thought about that. I had tried running the script as both administrator and as a user with administrative rights. However it feels like windows does funny things with permissions and user accounts when running scripts.